# how to export data from SQL in R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, export

I'm a beginner in R.

I have connection via ODBC to SQL DB:

```
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=OurServer; Database=OurDatabase;Uid=; Pwd=")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("exec ourTable"))`
```

I can view initdata. I would like to export data from ourTable and save it into Excel.

> {I find many information but this information is about how to save Table into SQL}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you need to output the data in initdata into an excel file. I would use the openxlsx package in R.

```
 library(openxlsx)

 dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;
                                    Server=OurServer; 
                                    Database=OurDatabase;
                                    Uid=;
                                    Pwd=")

 initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("exec ourTable"))`     

  #output the xlsx file
 write.xlsx(initdata,file = "file_name.xlsx")
```

I hope this helps.